# React Native - Accessing static variable on same class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I just moved from android to React Native recently. So need some help. Why I not able to access the variable on same class, for example when I call URL_API_SERVER from another class, it give me 'Undefined/api/v2'.

```
class Constant {
    static BASE_URL = 'https://xxxxx';
    static URL_API_SERVER = this.BASE_URL + '/api/v2';
    static STATIC_BASEURL = this.BASE_URL + '/static';
    static URLSTRING_FAQ = this.STATIC_BASEURL + '/FAQ.html';
    static URLSTRING_TOU = this.STATIC_BASEURL + '/TOU.html';
}

export default Constant;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using `static` variable, you cannot use `this`. You can access the static variable like below.

```
class Constant {
    static BASE_URL = 'https://xxxxx';
    static URL_API_SERVER = Constant.BASE_URL + '/api/v2';
    static STATIC_BASEURL = Constant.BASE_URL + '/static';
    static URLSTRING_FAQ = Constant.STATIC_BASEURL + '/FAQ.html';
    static URLSTRING_TOU = Constant.STATIC_BASEURL + '/TOU.html';
}

export default Constant;
```